# Find and replace nested array object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

How to find and replace over deep nested array object in javascript

I have a sample object name `obj` and filtered the object by `id, in , and out`(obj_res).
How to find and update the particular obj with `id fund` in `obj_res` in javascript as shown in expected output

I got stuck need help how to do in javascript

```
var obj_res = getValue("bank", "bank", "trans");
function getValue(send, receive, id){
   const temp = obj.map(e => Object.entries(e).map(([k, val]) => val)).flat(3)
    result_obj = temp.filter(x=>x.in ==send && && x=>x.out ==receive && x.id == id);
  return result_obj;}
```

```
//whole object input
var obj = [{
    "btob": [{
      "id": "trans",
      "in": "bank",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10,
    },{
      "id": "fund",
      "in": "bank",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    }],
    "ctob": [{
      "id": "trans",
      "in": "credit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 20
    },{
      "id": "fund",
      "in": "credit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    }]
}]
```

```
//resultant obj after filter by id , in ,out 
var obj_res =[{
  "id": "trans",
  "in": "bank",
  "out": "bank",
  "value": 10
 },{
 "id": "fund",
 "in": "bank",
 "out": "bank",
 "value": 10
}]
```

```
 Expected Output:
  res=[{
  "id": "trans",
  "in": "bank",
  "out": "bank",
  "value": 10
 },{
"id": "fund",
"in": "credit",
"out": "bank",
"value": 10
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

A little bit late to the party, heh. I needed to modify deeply nested objects too, and found no acceptable tool for that purpose. Then I've made this and pushed it to npm.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-and

This small lib can help with modifying nested objects in a lodash manner. E.g.,

```js
var findAnd = require("find-and");

const obj_res =[{
  "id": "trans",
  "in": "bank",
  "out": "bank",
  "value": 10
 },{
 "id": "fund",
 "in": "bank",
 "out": "bank",
 "value": 10
}];

findAnd.changeProps(obj_res, { id: 'fund' }, { in: 'credit' });
```

outputs exactly what you want.

https://runkit.com/arfeo/find-and

Hope this could help someone else.

Comment: Nice little helper. It'd be great if you added an `appendObject` method to add an object after the one that was found.

Comment: @MarkL added `insertObjectBefore` and `insertObjectAfter` functions to the lib.

Answer (score -1):

Use `find()` to get first instance if you think there is only one. Otherwise use `filter()` and loop over each to modify properties on each matching object

```js
var obj_res = [{
  "id": "trans",
  "in": "bank",
  "out": "bank",
  "value": 10
}, {
  "id": "fund",
  "in": "bank",
  "out": "bank",
  "value": 10
}]


var fund = obj_res.find(({id}) => id === 'fund'); // returns array element or false

if (fund) {
  fund.in = 'XXXXX';
  console.log(obj_res)
}
```